# Events are not firing (in non-IE browsers) when adding html elements dynamically via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, cross-browser

I'm creating an input element with focus and blur events via jQuery. For some reason even though input element is displayed the events are not firing. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/9JtLq/8/

This works in IE7 & IE8. It doesn't work in Firefox, Safari or Chrome. Why?

html

```
<div>
  Try to focus from one input to another.  
</div>

<div class="placeholder"/>

<div class="placeholder"/>

<div id="output" />
```

javascript:

```
var input_box = $("<input type=\"text\" />")
.focus(function() 
{
       $("#output").html($("#output").text() + "focus  - ");
})
.blur(function() 
{
      $("#output").html($("#output").text() + "blur  - "); 
});


$(".placeholder").append(input_box);
```

Comment: By all means use jsFiddle and such as an *adjunct* to your question, but always put the code *in* the question as well. SO should stand alone (external resources can disappear), and people looking to help you shouldn't have to follow the link to do so (though they can choose to).

Answer (score 1):

you should bind the event after you append

```
$(".placeholder").append("<input type=\"text\" />");

$(".placeholder input:text").focus(function() {
    $("#output").html($("#output").text() + "focus  - ");
}).blur(function() {
    $("#output").html($("#output").text() + "blur  - ");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9JtLq/9/

---

If you're using jQuery 1.4.1+ you can live bind blur and focus, meaning all current and future elements that match will be bound to the event(s)

```
$(".placeholder input:text").live("focus", function() {
    $("#output").html($("#output").text() + "focus  - ");
}).live("blur", function() {
    $("#output").html($("#output").text() + "blur  - ");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9JtLq/10/

Comment: Also, if you're using a jQuery version that does not support `.live`, you have the liveQuery plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery

Comment: Why do I have to bind the event after appending it?  Also I updated question, original code works in IE7 and IE8 but not in other browsers.

Comment: I'm assuming jQuery can't bind to events that don't exist yet unless you use the `live()` event. IE7 and IE8 might interact differently. If you use `live()` you should be good to go.